# How to add input how many integers do you want?

Tags: python, input, while-loop, integer

I'm starting next month full stack developer and im doing some practicing

i started with Python and i want to make some code
with while loop that will ask the user to input how many integers they want
and i want to calculate all the numbers

im doing something wrong not sure what
thanks in advance
oz

```
example:

number = int(input('Enter how many integer: '))
my_list = [number]
while len(my_list) < number:
    user_input = int(input('Enter a integer: '))
    my_list.append(user_input)
    print(user_input+number)    
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input('Enter how many integer: '))
my_list = []
while len(my_list) < number:
    user_input = int(input('Enter a integer: '))
    my_list.append(user_input)
    print(user_input, ' ' ,number)    
print(my_list)
```